# How to scale element to fit the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a div when the user clicks a link.

The div will first be very small then scale to fit the browser screen.

I have something so far.

```
<a id='btn' href='#' ><img src='test.png' /></a>
```

css

```
.test1{ 
    position: absolute;
    transition:all 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s; /* Safari */
}
```

js

```
var contentDiv = document.createElement('div');
var img        = document.createElement('img');

contentDiv.setAttribute('class','test1');

img.src='newimg.png';
contentDiv.appendChild(img);

$("#btn").on('click', function(e){
   $('body').append(contentDiv)
   var setW = $(contentDiv).width()/2
   var setH = $(contentDiv).height()/2
   var xPos = e.pageX - setW
   var yPos = e.pageY - setH
   $(contentDiv).css('transform', 'scale(.1)') //first very small
   $(contentDiv).css({top: yPos, left: xPos, 'transform': 'scale(2)'}) //second fit the screen
})
```

I am not sure how to create a smaller div then scale to fit the windows. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: instead of using scale why cant you increase width and height of a div to 100% ?

Comment: if so, how do I start with a smaller div to fit the screen?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using scale, you can just increase height and width of the div to 100%. Created Example for you [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/oxzs5l88)

Comment: thanks, that's helpful, could you please help on start from smaller div to fit the screen too? +1

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use css transitions to achieve the same thing:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #294059;
}
.overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 0px; /* This can be... */
    width: 0px; /* ...any size you want */
    background: #562906;
}
.overlay.active {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function() {
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active'); //Alternatively, add a dedicated 'close' button that removes the class
});
```

This is obviously a very basic implementation, but the basic concept can be extended to suit your needs.  Also, the advantage of using CSS transitions is that you reduce the logic of your jQuery to the addition/removal of a class on your overlay container, and avoid injecting inline styles.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8fD/1/)